# can't perform a for loop with iteration in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, iteration

I am developing a **games library** where I can add or delete my games.
So far I just made a list with 3 games in standard, but when i was trying to test it. It gave me an error.

I am trying to do it with an iteration on my vector, but for some reason it won't work. And i can't find that reason.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector<int>::const_iterator iter;

vector<string> games;
games.push_back("Crysis 2");
games.push_back("God of War 3");
games.push_back("FIFA 12");

cout <<"Welcome to your Games Library.\n";
cout <<"These are your games:\n";
for (iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout <<*iter <<endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably you should say what the actual error is rather than just letting people guess. Good that you included full code though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the types of you iterator and your vetcor are incompatible.

use:

```
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
```

To make things easier it might be better to typedef your collection type:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> GamesListType;
GamesListType::const_iterator iter;
GamesListType games;
```

Comment: I just can't believe i didn't saw that. Thanks for the other information!!

Answer (score 2):

your iterator doesn't match the container type: declare this way

```
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
```

Comment: of course!! I feel so stupid right now. Thanks for the answer on my silly post :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate a `string` vector with an `int` const iterator. Change your iterator type.

Comment: Its alright. i'm voting to close this so no more answers are posted. you better accept an answer.